# Download went much faster than my connection speed

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, google-chrome, download, dropbox

I'm looking for an explanation to that mystery mentioned below. I'm not having a problem that needs to be solved.

I have an ADSL line with speed as 8 megabits/sec, usually I get download speed as 850 KB/sec average

This morning I was downloading a file from Dropbox website using Chrome. Once I clicked the download link the download started to my Downloads folder, with a speed of 4.5 MB/sec, that's more than 5 times my connection speed.

I suspected that my ISP was too generous today, but I checked my router stats page and I found the speed was 8192 (or 8191) which is typical.

I thought of maybe dropbox is using a nearby data center and a reverse proxy, but it still does not make sense as I'm eventually limited by the capacity of the connection speed.

I think it's worth mentioning that I'm on a WiFi network, no eth cable.

Comment: You say it *started* at 4.8MB/sec.  I assume that wasn't sustained?  If so, then it is probably just a averaging error at the beginning of the download.

Comment: No, it stayed static or close to static until the download finishes.

Comment: Did the download time at that rate add up to the total size of the file? you are mixing about 3 readings, and any one of them could be being misrepresented to you.

Comment: What was the file size approximately anyway? Assuming that you are not using a local proxy, I don't think that the WiFi matters much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your modem shows you that it's connected at 8mbps, your connection can not exceed it.

What you saw is most likely due to a bad estimate from your browser.  This will happen for many reasons including:

- The computer's performance at the moment you clicked the link was affected by something else and then it quickly came back to normal.
- The fact that speeds are only visible (from the all downloads page) while the transfer is in progress only allows you to see the last estimate before it disappears.
- The actual time it took for the HTTP download connection to be established could have mislead the browser's estimate.
- The size of the file you downloaded.
- Live download compression, which is becoming more and more common.  Since it is compressed live, the browser can not know what the resulting size will be before it completes.

Speed tests are always slightly unreliable because many factors come into play that can not be validated at any level.

Using an actual speed test site that is very close to you, ideally on your ISP's network, will give you the most reliable results as it will try to overcome common factors that could mislead it, as well as using a test file big enough to provide a suitable answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your ISP has to throttle connections down to your advertised speed, though the line is generally capable of much higher speeds.

The answer above suggests it was likely an averaging or display error, but this is much less likely than that your connection simply took a moment to throttle down to the speed you pay for.

I have witnessed this with many different connections, from different ISP's. As far as the factors that lead to this happening, I am unsure. It might have something to do with how ISP's handle those requests on their end, and I would think if anything it was due to a high number of requests which lead to that connection being handled differently.I would suspect the server you were downloading from was close to you, and as far as making that happen again, you probably can't, it's mostly a fluke.